# Centered container with text on the left and squared image on the right?

Tags: html, css, alignment, responsive

I'm losing my mind here over something that seems to be very simple, but after playing around for several hours I thought it was time to ask for some help.

What I need is a container (see pink colour) that is centered on the page and is 70% of the page it's width. Then there should be two Divs inside of the container.

One of the left for text, and one on the right for a square image that should stay at a fixed size (Let's say 200x200px - I mean, it looks so weird to end up having a 50x50px avatar next to a block of text after scaling your browser down). It's OK if the right Div shifts below the first Div on mobile devices.

I haven't been able to find a useful answer on here, but I've been playing around with the code below (which does the opposite - small (image) block on the left) but for some reason I just can't get it to work.

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper div {
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}
#one {
  background-color: gray;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 140px;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
}
#two {
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px dashed #ccc;
  min-height: 170px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #one {
    float: none;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: auto;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="one">one</div>
  <div id="two">two</div>
</div>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

[Image with what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6uXP.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `flexbox`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 1000px;    /* added this to limit its width on very wide screens  */
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper div {
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}
#one {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: gray;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
}
#two {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px dashed #ccc;
  width: 200px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #one {
    border-right: none;
  }
  #two {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="one">one</div>
  <div id="two">two</div>
</div>
```

Another option for wide screens would be an additional `media query`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper div {
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}
#one {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: gray;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
}
#two {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px dashed #ccc;
  width: 200px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #one {
    border-right: none;
  }
  #two {
    width: auto;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="one">one</div>
  <div id="two">two</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great, thanks! Seems to do the trick.

Would it also be possible to set a "max" to the width of the whole div?

I notice that the text and header in div "one" would become ugly and stretched over one line if you'd view a page on, let's say, a 27 inch monitor. 

A Max-width on the Wrapper doesn't seem to do the trick? Does that conflict with the Flex method?

    .wrapper {
      display: flex;
      background-color: #f5f3f1;
      width: 70%;
      max-width: 75%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border: 0px solid #000;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

Comment: @Kevin11 Well, in your suggestion you have `max-width: 75%;` and the width is only 70%;, so nothing will happen. Use a fixed unit instead, like `px`, and it will work. Updated my answer with such.

Comment: @Kevin11 If my answer solved your question, please consider accept it, if not, let me know how I can update it so it does.

Comment: Thanks so much, that's it! Have a great day!